# What type of problem is this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I am attempting to tutor my niece in algebra and they don't have actual text books anymore.  They evidently just come home with problems.  In this case the teacher just said to just think about it and give an answer, but that doesn't seem right.  I am trying to find more examples and maybe an actual lesson to give context to this but am having trouble finding anything on line.  So here is the problem:

given A and B are populations and $A > B$, determine if expressions are $>,\, <$ or $=$.

$$\frac {A-B}B \quad \quad \quad  A-\frac BB$$

I've worked it out for her substituting numbers for variables to show her that the left side is < the right side (unless $A =2,\,B=1$ in which case they are equal) and have the answer for this particular problem.  But what kind of problem is this and where can I find more about them.  With no text book to fall back on I am a bit lost.

Comment: Perhaps 'inequalities'?

Comment: This looks hard to parse.  Are you saying $\frac {A-B}B$ vs $A-\frac BB$?  But the latter is $A-1$, no?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Sorry if I typed it badly. I don't know how to make it look like you did on the screen.  I am afraid I am not too savvy on the keyboard. I am more the pencil and paper type

Comment: Ok.  But then they are equal whenever $B=1$.  The left hand is $\frac AB -1$ and the right is $A-1$ so equality requires $\frac AB =A$ which implies $B=1$.  More generally, not sure what a "population" is.  Are we to assume that $A,B$ are positive integers?  If so then $B>1\implies \frac AB<A$ so other than $B=1$ the left hand is smaller.

Comment: Yes, with less of the jargon I got the same answer.  I am very rusty with tat stuff.  I just wish I had my ole text books to share with her.  A lesson plan or something.  I will look up inequalities and see if that helps me. Thanks

Comment: I'm surprised they don't give out some sort of materials.  Doesn't have to be a text, but I'd have expected some sort of handouts (or online materials).  What grade is this?

Comment: I am just a guy who did well in math years ago trying to help my niece.  This community may be a bit overkill for my needs.  The people here are way smarter and more technical than I ever was.  Thanks for the info though.

Comment: 9th grade. She just brought home a sheet with problems but no explanations or examples

Comment: I think they are trying to teach fractions, "if two fractions have same denominator then we need only the numerator to find out which fraction is bigger", $\frac{A-B}{B}, \frac{AB-B}{B}$ and "how to form two given fractions so that both have equal denominator"

Comment: I think that by saying the $A$ and $B$ represent **populations** the teacher is implying that they are positive whole numbers, such as the populations of a city. ($B\ne0$ since it is in the denominator) But even then, there is not a definitive answer since, for example if $B=1$ the two expressions yield equal values, otherwise the expression on the right is always larger.

Comment: It looks like it could be any of (1) inequalities, (2) fractions, or (3) basic algebra (having to rearrange numbers to determine relations). My guess is (1), since that is the main focus of the question.